# access the value of map key, key is sobject

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have a map called employeeMap and its build of {{sobject}:array()} looks like this

```
{employeeFunction__c:{Id=a1s2C000000S3yRQAS,
                      Name=dev 1, 
                      empolyeeRole__c=a1m2C000000cK9aQAE, 
                      Total_Hours__c=20.00}
                      : Array(5)
                      }
```

if i do this

```
for(var key in employeeMap){
   console.log(key);
   }
```

I get this

```
employeeFunction__c:{Id=a1s2C000000S3yRQAS, 
                     Name=dev 1, 
                     emplyeeRole__c=a1m2C000000cK9aQAE, 
                     Total_Hours__c=20.00
                     }
```

Goal: is to get the id of the key
if i do this

```
for(var key in employeeMap){
   console.log(key.Id);
   }
```

result is **undefined**

Comment: it will be nice if they leave comment of why they downgrade the question, for future improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have two nested objects, how about something like this.

```
for( let key in employeeMap ){
    for( let item in key ) {
       console.log(item.Id);
    }
}
```

As `key` is an object also try to use something like `key[employeeFunction__c]` on if you are using a single loop.

Comment: console.log(object.Id); gave me undefined,  console.log(object); gave me count of number like 0,1,2,3..,console.log(object[key]); gave me broken down string of the object like e,m,p,l,o,y..

Comment: How about `console.log( item )` I updated my example

Comment: console.log( item ) is returning number of char in the object like 0,1,2,3,4,5,...

Comment: How about `console.log( key[ item ] );`

Comment: console.log( key[ item ] ); is returning a broken char, its like making the object string and returning broken chars it looks like this e,m,p,l,o,y,e,e,F,u,n,c,t,i,o,n,_,_,c,:,{,I,d,.. instead of comma new line

Comment: I see would you mind pasting your initial object in a formated way, in multiple lines instead of a single one to have a better visual hint. Thank you

Comment: Its seems like its reading key as string not an object cause i wast able to do key.replace('employeeFunction__c:','');

Comment: What's the result of `console.log( employeeMap['employeeFunction__c'] );` and `console.log( employeeMap['employeeFunction__c']['Id'] );`

Comment: both are resulting in undefined